# Typing a capital letter in a password submits the password in Windows Command Prompt, can't disable

Tags: windows, cmd, readline

I got my laptop setup with PowerShell and CMD, (I support a lot of remote machines, using SSH a lot) and when I try to login to a machine with a capital letter in the password, as soon as I press shift+letter, whatever I've typed so far gets submitted, it rejects the password (obviously) and the capital letter shows up as input on the next line. What am I missing? This happens in stock CMD, CMD with Clink, and PowerShell. Let me know if additional information is needed.

Comment: You sure you're pressing shift & not ctrl? Also, check that the ctrl key isn't stuck down.

Comment: Also does this happen with both left and right shift keys? And have you accidentally enabled sticky keys?

Comment: Yep, definitely shift, see below, also doing it with Caps Lock. Also happens with right shift as well.

Comment: (Ignoring the fact you didn't answer the question about enabled sticky keys), based upon your comments etc. you have a software or hardware issue. This site is for programming issues, so, on this occasion, you have chosen the wrong 'stack' platform. [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) is better suited to software and hardware issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

> CapsLock

Instead of

> Shift?

Does it work then? If is still doesnt work, there could be a problem with the keyboard or the CMD is configured improperly

Comment: What a good idea! That does the same thing however! I am using a USB keyboard, so I tried it with the built-in laptop keyboard and got the same thing. It seems like some kind of setting somewhere, but I have no idea where to look for it, and I haven't been able to find anything on the search engines =/